Application of boundary condition finite difference scheme
I am solving a version of the Laplace equation on a square ($a<x<b$, $0<y<h$) grid using finite differences.
I have an analytical solution to my problem so I can easily check the correctness of my numerical solution. What I am struggling with is the application of the boundary condition at the point $y=h$, this condition reads
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y=h)}{\partial y}=-\alpha\frac{\partial^{2}f(x,y=h)}{\partial y^{2}},$$
where $\alpha$ is a constant that changes depending on the problem that is being considered. The other conditions are all fairly standard $f(x=a,y)=f(x=b,y)=0$ and $f(x,y=0)=x$. I have used second-order accurate finite difference descriptions for the terms in the Laplace equation but am at a bit of a loss as to how to correctly implement the above condition.
As ever, any help, guidance or hints much appreciated.
Additional details included below -
I have discretized as follows:
$$\frac{f_{i+1}^{j}-2f_{i}^{j}+f_{i}^{j-1}}{(\Delta x)^{2}}+\frac{f_{i}^{j+1}-2f_{i}^{j}+f_{i}^{j-1}}{(\Delta y)^{2}}=0,$$
and am then using a simple Jacobi method with $\Delta x=\Delta y$, to compute $f_{i}^{j}$:
$$(f_{i}^{j})^{k+1}=(1/4)[(f_{i+1}^{j})^{k}+(f_{i}^{j-1})^{k}+(f_{i}^{j+1})^{k}+(f_{i}^{j-1})^{k}],$$
the computation iterates until a certain tolerance is achieved. The three 'standard' conditions mentioned above are simple to implement. I have attempted to implement the fourth condition as follows:
$$\frac{f_{i}^{j+1}-f_{i}^{j-1}}{2\Delta y}+\alpha\frac{f_{i}^{j+1}-2f_{i}^{j}+f_{i}^{j-1}}{(\Delta y)^{2}}=0,$$
rearranging for $f_{i}^{j+1}$ gives
$$f_{i}^{j+1}=\frac{4\alpha}{(2\alpha+\Delta y)}f_{i}^{j}-\frac{(2\alpha-\Delta y)}{(2\alpha+\Delta y)}f_{i}^{j-1},$$
at each iteration $k$, I then enforce this condition at the points where $y=h$, i.e., index $j+1$ in the above condition corresponds directly to all points on $y=h$.

Please. Show us your method.

Additional info added.
